# Woocommerce price output on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to mod a plugin for my needs. Plugin code is as follow:

```
1. update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', (isset($product['price']) && !empty($product['price'])) ? $product['price'] : '');
2. update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', (isset($product['sale-price']) && !empty($product['sale-price']) && ($product['sale-price']<$product['price']) ) ? $product['sale-price'] : '');
3. update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', (isset($product['price'])) ? $product['price'] : '');
```

First two rows input the regular price and discount (sale) price values into the database. The third row is the output on the product page, which I need to change so:

1. If discounted price `_sale_price / [sale-price]` is present it should be shown as default `_price / [price]` on row 3.
2. If discount price `_sale_price / [sale-price]` is not present the normal price from row 1 should be shown as [price] on row 3

I've tried `if (isset($product['sale-price'])){? $product['sale-price'] : '';}else{? $product['price'] : '';}` but this throws 500 error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This seems very strange - WooCommerce automatically computes the price from the regular price, sale price and the from/to sales date. Why are you trying to override this?

Comment: The plugin I am using overrides the default behavior of woocommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce should be doing this automatically, but in the interest of answering your question, there are some errors in your code, it seems like you are trying to mix a ternery operator with an IF statement.

The correct replacement for line 3 should look like this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', (isset($product['sale-price']) && !empty($product['sale-price'])) ? $product['sale-price'] : $product['price']);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The problem is, that the plugin overrides the default behavior of woocommerce. 

One more question: for lines 2 and 3, how can I check for one more variable (retail-price) if (sale-price) do not exist or is empty?

Comment: I'm glad to have helped :) Sorry, but I don't quite understand your question - do you want to rephrase that for me?

Answer (score 1):

My final working code is as follow:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', (isset($product['price']) && !empty($product['price'])) ? $product['price'] : '');

update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', (isset($product['sale-price']) && !empty($product['sale-price']) && ($product['sale-price']<$product['price'])) ? $product['sale-price'] : ((isset($product['retail-price']) && !empty($product['retail-price']) && ($product['retail-price']<$product['price'])) ? $product['retail-price'] : '')); 

update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', (isset($product['sale-price']) && !empty($product['sale-price'])) ? $product['sale-price'] : ((isset($product['retail-price']) && !empty($product['retail-price'])) ? $product['retail-price'] : $product['price']));
```

Thanks to [Frits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6049581/frits) for the help. :)